# PODS_ROOT and other pods env variables not set when compiling Ionic app

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, intercom, intercom-ios

I have built an Ionic 2 app which uses Intercom (a third-party extension).  Intercom is installed using cocoapods.

When compiling my app I am given the errors:

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

This is being generated by the Build Phase `[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock`:

```
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
# This output is used by Xcode 'outputs' to avoid re-running this script phase.
echo "SUCCESS" > "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
```

I have tried outputting the environment variables `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH` and `PODS_ROOT` in the `STDERROR` `echo` from the script above and both are blank.  I can probably get around this specific error by amending those paths myself, but clearly something else more fundamental is broken, so I need to fix the actual issue itself.

Why are these variables blank?

I have additional build phases for `[CP] Copy Pods Resources` and `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` which run some shell scripts.  I have tried changing the order of these with no luck.

My Podfile.lock and Podfile (which was auto-generated anyway) both seem good:

Podfile:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'niix' do
    project 'niix.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Intercom', '~> 3.2.2'
end
```

Podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
  - Intercom (3.2.12)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Intercom (~> 3.2.2)

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Intercom: 3119e8ebf76d3da425bab717a08067398fcabfe6

PODFILE CHECKSUM: f99283bb8a4e56cb037a02390d2fbc4e76c97db9

COCOAPODS: 1.3.1
```

There are no errors when running `pod install`, and all files I expect are present.

Things I have tried already:

- Running `pod install` (of course)
- Running `pod deintegrate`, running Product > Clean in XCode, re-running `pod install`
- Manually deleting the `Podfile.lock` and `Pods` directory, running a Clean in XCode and then re-running `pod install`
- A good nights sleep and another attempt the next morning!

Things to note:

- I am running from `project.xcworkspace` not `project.xcodeproj`
- I am running the latest stable version of XCode 8.3.3
- I am running the latest version of Cocoapods 1.3.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've spent a long time trying to work this out and got nowhere.  The app was built using Ionic 2, so the actual source code is stored elsewhere and built into a native XCode application.

Because of this I decided to delete the entire XCode directory.  `.xcodeproj`, `.xcworkspace`, everything.  I then rebuilt from Ionic.

On the second build I saw thats the `Pods` directory was there and everything was as it should be.  I could compile and run first time without any issue.

My assumption is that the first build failed because I didn't have Cocoapods installed, so Ionic silently failed to run the `pod install` command upon set up.  I guess it does something a little different to a traditional setup which is why I couldn't just run `pod install` afterwards.

So, in short, this was fixed by removing the iOS project:

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
```

And re-adding it:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

And then building:

```
ionic cordova run ios --device
```

But make sure you already have Cocoapods installed on your system first.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been researching this for 2 days and never thought of removing the platform. This is the only fix that worked for me.

Comment: Legend. Have tried several fixes elsewhere and this was the only one that worked.   Had the same scenario where I didn't have cocoapods installed at first.