# Ionic project, iOS emulator in Xcode, error: Podfile.lock: No such file, PODS_ROOT empty

Tags: xcode, cordova, cocoapods

This question, from a year ago, never got an answer:

[Xcode /Podfile.lock: No such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769333/xcode-podfile-lock-no-such-file)

I am having exactly the same issue. I'd like to re-open the question.

I have a Cordova/Ionic app, which also uses Firebase, via CocoaPods.

I've never worked with any of this tech before, I'm simply taking over the project because the original developer left. I don't know anything about Cordova or Ionic or Mac iOS.

I ran:

```
pod install
```

and that ran without error. If I do:

```
 ls -alhrt platforms/ios/
```

I see:

```
 pods-release.xcconfig
 pods-debug.xcconfig
 ..
 cordova
 www
 platform_www
 CordovaLib
 .gitignore
 Cher
 frameworks.json
 pods.json
 Cher.xcworkspace
 ios.json
 build
 .DS_Store
 Podfile
 Cher.xcodeproj
 .
 Pods
 Podfile.lock
```

So the file "Pods" exists, and also "Podfile.lock".

However, if I open this project in Xcode, and try to build, I get the error:

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory 
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory 
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

This error is common and when I searched on Google, there were dozens of pages addressing this issue. For instance:

https://support.layer.com/hc/en-us/articles/204301594-I-m-getting-a-The-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-Podfile-lock-error-How-do-I-fix-it-

Which suggests:

```
Deleting the Podfile.lock file in your project folder

Deleting the Pods folder in your project folder

Execute 'pod install' in your project folder

Do a "Clean" in Xcode

Rebuild your project
```

I've done this repeatedly, but I still get the same error.

Again, if I use the `ls` command, I can see the file `Podfile.lock` but Xcode continues to complain that the file doesn't exist.

I believe the solution is something similar to what they tried here:

`PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH and PODS_ROOT not defined`

`https://discuss.multi-os-engine.org/t/pods-podfile-dir-path-and-pods-root-not-defined/823`

If I do:

```
grep -iR PODS_ROOT *
```

I see:

```
Cher.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:             "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseInvites/Resources/GINInviteResources.bundle",
Cher.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:             "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseInvites/Resources/GPPACLPickerResources.bundle",
Cher.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:             "${PODS_ROOT}/GTMOAuth2/Source/Touch/GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib",
Cher.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:             "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleSignIn/Resources/GoogleSignIn.bundle",
Cher.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:             "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock",
```

So if PODS_ROOT is empty, that would explain why Xcode can not find Manifest.lock.

But where and how do I set PODS_ROOT?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is here:

[PODS_ROOT and other pods env variables not set when compiling Ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110728/pods-root-and-other-pods-env-variables-not-set-when-compiling-ionic-app)

---

So, in short, this was fixed by removing the iOS project:

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
```

And re-adding it:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

And then building:

```
ionic cordova run ios --device
```

But make sure you already have Cocoapods installed on your system first.

Comment: This was the solution for me, plus making sure ionic was updated before adding the platform by running `npm i -g ionic`